# Exploring Android Platform Code in Eclipse (Java and C++)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

I am exploring Android platform source code. I'd like to understand how parts of the platform are implemented. I am looking for a way to leverage Eclipse's java development tools and C/C++ development tools to explore the code efficiently. I need a way for Eclipse to find related code in different sub-modules. For example I'd like to have "show declaration" facility (ctrl+mouse click) that will take to source code located in different directory/module.
I need to be able to explore Java and C/C++ platform code in same Eclipse window.
I don't dream about Java to JNI C++ code traversal, just inside same language (Java-to-Java and C++-to-C++). I also don't dream about traversal from C library code to kernel code.

Are you aware of a way to make Eclipse import every sub-module of Android platform as separate project while retaining dependencies/includes, or any other way to make code browsing easy?

I have stumbled upon some commercial Eclipse distribution that does it (don't remember it name), but nothing free/flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You may install CDT and create project for native part needed or as whole. But it is not as good as source insight for c/c++ parts.